# format is changing SSRS Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting

See this Image below
http://i46.tinypic.com/2pt6jkn.jpg
This is report in SSRS as shown when it is uploaded in the server.

On my developement machine, the format is ok as shown in the pic below.
http://i48.tinypic.com/be9dmh.jpg

Why is the format getting messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually has to do with level of zoom and format being displayed in.  Basically, your mileage with the anti-aliasing of ssrs will vary.  If you print or export to pdf you should see it correctly though.  The web view just isn't great.